# Why does python say colon is expected but I already have one?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RryBi.png)

Please help... Thanks

Comment: Please put the code on the question body not on images

Comment: Use `elif` for conditions

Comment: it wont let me since I am a new user

Comment: `else` expects no condition either use `elif` like @HKG said or remove it

Comment: ive tried elif, it also didnt work

Comment: Nevermind, thank you guys you've helped a lot, I was incorrect I had elif before but It didn't work, now it seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `else` doesn't get a condition, it is implied by what comes before it.

```
a = 4
b = 3
if a < b:
 print("hello")
else:   # <-- no condition
 print("bye")
```

[check this out](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) for a tutorial, where you also find information on `elif`

Answer (score 0):

You don't Even have to provide a condition in 'else' part,
this works like,

for example

```
if ( a > 100):
    #[Apply changes or operations under a condition if a is greater than 100.]

else:
    #[Apply changes or operations under a condition if a is less than or equal to 100.].
```

If want to put a condition there then just use 'elif' instead of 'else'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't actually about a missing colon. It thinks there is a missing colon because there is supposed to be a colon immediately after the "else". Instead, you have "totalRevenue...".

Remember that an `else` is not supposed to have a condition - `else` is supposed to mean whatever is leftover that wasn't covered in all of your other conditions.

If you want to have a condition, you should use `elif` instead of `else`.